# MySQL connection timeout?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I have a spring-mvc application running on glassfish server with Mysql db connection in which the pool idle time is set to 300 seconds but I am getting continuously the Warnings every 5 minutes even if ther is no idle session even if the application is up in the server but no one is using it:

Unexpected exception while destroying resource from pool MediaTrackPool. Exception message: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [com.mysql.jdbc.ProfilerEventHandlerFactory], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped

Error while Resizing pool MediaTrackPool. Exception : WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped

Could someone help me in getting rid of this warnings as or restricting them when actual ideal session is encountered because getting the warnings every 5 minutes even when no one using the application is not helping is real log analysis.

Settings for connection pool are as below:
General Settings
Pool Name: MediaTrackPool
Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource
Datasource Classname:com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource

Pool Settings
Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 8
Maximum Pool Size: 32
Pool Resize Quantity: 2
Idle Timeout: 300
Max Wait Time: 60000

Answer (score 0):

I belive that there is a mismatch between the connection pool properties and the actual timeouts at the my sql server.

Can you check whats the value of `connect_timeout`, `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout`.

More info on setting these timouts is [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server).